# Do Solar Cells Regenerate After Exposure to Ionising Radiation?

Tags: particle-physics, radiation, space, space-travel, solar-cells

In the past, plenty of research has been done on the effects of ionising radiation on solar cells. This is due to the importance of high efficiency solar cells for electric spacecraft propulsion. Such spacecraft would presumably need to travel through the infamous Van Allen Belts, and the low thrust of ion engines can increase time spent in the belts to nearly 400 days.

The radiation encountered in the belts reduces the efficiency of Silicon and Gallium Arsenide solar cells, as explained in [this paper](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/b180707.pdf). However, to my knowledge little research has been done on the ability of these solar cells to recover from the damage.

Are Silicon and/or Gallium Arsenide cells capable of recovery from the damage caused by ionising radiation, and if so, to what extent?

Comment: Electronic energy loss, yes. Displacement damage (nuclear energy loss) not so much - it slowly builds up, reducing efficiency. I'm not sure anybody has provisions for annealing the solar cells, as they do for, e.g., detectors at CERN.

Comment: Some spacecraft have successfully used annealing, I believe, to "refresh" solar arrays but this does not help the blackening of the conductive glass covering the arrays.  The blackening occurs because of damage from ionizing radiation, thus reducing the amount of transmitted light to the arrays over time.

Comment: @honeste_vivere - good point on the coatings - the build up of color centers will have an impact, and those are much harder to anneal out.